# Disable Context Menu on a a child of a root JavaFX TreeView<Label> with TreeItem<Label>

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

A JavaFX 14 `Treview` with `TreeItem<Label>` in this structure;

- Root

  - Group

    - Child
  - Group

    - Child
    - Child

I have attached a `ContextMenu` to the `Label` at the Root to add and remove Groups. And I am able to disable the Remove Groups when there are no groups using;

```
removeGroupMenuItem.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(treeView.getRoot().getChildren()));
```

However, I have now attached `ContextMenu` to the `Label` of each Group that allows adding a child or removing all children. My question is, how can I disable the Remove All Children `MenuItem` if one or more Groups are selected.

I have tried which does not work;

```
removeAllChildrenMenuItem.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().stream().flatMap(f -> f.getChildren().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == 0, treeView.selectionModelProperty()));
```

Any thought welcome!

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: View components like `Label` shouldn't be used as the type of other components like `TreeView<Lable>` or `TreeItem<Label>`.

Comment: @M.S. can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: `Model` represents a business object. A `View` is a visual representation of that object. When you use a `TreeView<T>`, the `T` should be your `Model`.

Comment: Thx @M.S. can you suggest another way to attach a ContextMenu to the TreeItem?

Comment: You don't attach a `ContextMenu` to a `TreeItem`, you attach it to the `TreeCell` of that item. So, yes. You can set a cell factory to your `TreeView`, override `updateItem(object, boolean)` method and use `setContextMenu(contextMenu)`.

Comment: Thanks @M.S. I shall look at that, however does doing so lead to a resolution for the posted problem ?

Comment: @cbm64, I strongly recommend you to do so, but no, it wouldn't solve your problem directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Binding` will not be invalidated because your code waits for the `SelectionModel` property to be changed, not the selected items:

```java
Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().stream().flatMap(f -> f.getChildren().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == 0, treeView.selectionModelProperty());
```

You can fix that by changing the dependencies of the binding:

```java
Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().stream().flatMap(f -> f.getChildren().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == 0, treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

**Note:** If you change the tree's selection model by using `treeView.setSelectionModel(...)` anywhere else in your code, you have to rebind  `disable` property again. If this is a common thing in your code, you can add a dependency to the selection model so the code become like this:

```java
Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {...}, treeView.selectionModelProperty(), treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

That means, recalculate the value whenever the selection model or the selected items change.